# Fixed-point iteration problem

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation $$5e^{-(x-2))^2}-x^4+1=0$$ has one positive solution (around $1.48194$) and one negative solution (around $-1.00015$). In this exercise, the original equation is rearranged into the form $x=g(x)$, and the fixed-point iterative method is used to seek the solution.
Given the initial guess $x_0=1$, find a form of $g(x)$ such that the iterative process converges to the positive solution.
Given the initial guess $x_0=1$, find a form of $g(x)$ such that the iterative process converges to the negative solution.
Given the initial guess $x_0=10$, find a form of $g(x)$ such that the iterative process converges to the positive solution.
So we have $x=\left(5e^{-(x-2)^2}+1\right)^{1/4}$ and substituting $x_0=1$ into this we eventually get $1.00015$ so I’m not sure where I am going wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got there by writing $x^4=5e^{-(x-2)^2}+1$ and taking the fourth root, but you ignored the fact that the fourth root can be negative.  If you want the negative root you need to write $x=-\left(5e^{-(x-2)^2}+1\right)^{1/4}$ and iterate that.

Comment: Right thanks. If we wanted the positive solution start at $x_0=1$ then would we rearrange to make the $x$ in the exponential part the subject?

Comment: You need to make $|g'(x)| \lt 1$ at the root.  That would likely be a good way to go because the log function varies rather slowly.  I haven't tried it.